# Can't rewrite 3rd party module Block class

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to rewrite the following class from a 3rd party module:

```
Magestore_Storelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Storelocator_Edit_Tab_Generalinfo
```

I've declared the module in `Holy_Storelocator.xml`.

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Holy_Storelocator>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
      <depends>
          <Magestore_Storelocator />
      </depends>
    </Holy_Storelocator>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Then I created a `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Holy_Storelocator>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Holy_Storelocator>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <storelocator>
        <class>Holy_Storelocator_Helper</class>
      </storelocator>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <storelocator>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_storelocator_edit_tab_generalinfo>Holy_Storelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Storelocator_Edit_Tab_Generalinfo</adminhtml_storelocator_edit_tab_generalinfo>
                <!-- Magestore_Storelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Storelocator_Edit_Tab_Generalinfo -->
            </rewrite>
        </storelocator>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

And finally I created the class:

```
<?php
class Holy_Storelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Storelocator_Edit_Tab_Generalinfo extends Magestore_Storelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Storelocator_Edit_Tab_Generalinfo
{
    protected function _prepareForm() {
    // code ommitted

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still extend the magestore class, just use

```
return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form::_prepareForm();
```

instead of

```
return parent::_prepareForm();
```

This will skip the parent class's _prepareForm but still keep the rest of the inheritance chain intact.

Comment: thanks.  In the end I used an observer but this is good to know

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the `return parent::_prepareForm();` in my class was calling the original class which I was trying to override and ovewriting my changes.

To fix the issue I made my class extend from extend from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form`

```
<?php
class Holy_Storelocator_Block_Adminhtml_Storelocator_Edit_Tab_Generalinfo extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    //code here
}
```

So I guess `return parent::_prepareForm();` is a common cause for messing up Magento Class re-writes.

I found that an observer was a better method to use here afterall.